# how to see original created date of attached xml in mail?

Tags: xml, email, outlook

Some body has created one xml file on particular day. and he is sending to me by attaching that. but i am opening that mail attachment after one month. but i would like to know the actual file created date of xml which is attached. how to know that? any hacking also ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The date a file is created on is a function of the operating system and is not normally part of the file itself.

That is, if you save the file on your system, it will show as created on the date it was saved.

Comment: word files and all we can see know

Comment: @Vetrivelmp - I don't understand that.

Comment: if you open an attached word file in outlook i think you can see actual created date. please check and let me know.

Comment: @Vetrivelmp - I though you are asking about XML files?

Comment: yes like that is there any way to see xml file actual created date?. becaues in your answer also you did not mention any file type right?

Comment: @Vetrivelmp - Word and some other office formats have additional metadata as part of the file format. This is not metadata that a text file (such as an XML file) has.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a file along with original metadata like created date etc, you can zip or archive it then send via email or any mean.

when the receiver unzip, file will show the original date when the sender has created it.